# running delayed_job on each app server or on a separate instance?

Tags: delayed-job, engineyard

We're migrating our application www.monaqasat.com from a single server to a distributed infrastructure and we're debating where to run delayed_job from. The two obvious options are:

- From each app instance?
- From a single (or redundant) utility server?

Any recommendations or pros/cons?

Comment: oh okay so delayed _job is a product. i thought you want to run some cron jobs at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a single utility server unless it starts to get overwhelming for a single server.

I would also look at Gearman- http://gearman.org/.

If you need some serious messaging then RabbitMq http://www.rabbitmq.com/ is a good choice.